# Active-Active minio cluster sync data

Tags: kubernetes, minio

https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/replication/enable-server-side-two-way-bucket-replication.html#required-permissions

I follow this guide, when I do "mc admin policy add". I got an err:

```
mc: <ERROR> Unable to add new policy: conditions are not supported for action s3:GetBucketVersioning.
```

Then I add '--debug':

```
mc: <DEBUG> PUT /minio/admin/v3/add-canned-policy?name=ReplicationRemoteUserPolicy.json HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx:xxx
User-Agent: MinIO (linux; amd64) madmin-go/0.0.1 mc/RELEASE.2022-07-06T14-54-36Z
Content-Length: 1328
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=admin/20220707//s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=**REDACTED**
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: 26a5f72146edcd356b967fb84a6b1407418205af1904f9408fd2e85b196c98d1
X-Amz-Date: 20220707T094030Z

mc: <DEBUG> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 237
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 07 Jul 2022 09:40:19 GMT
Server: MinIO
Vary: Origin
X-Amz-Request-Id: 16FF82A1BB2425B5
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

{"Code":"XMinioMalformedIAMPolicy","Message":"conditions are not supported for action s3:GetBucketVersioning","Resource":"/minio/admin/v3/add-canned-policy","RequestId":"16FF82A1BB2425B5","HostId":"3473e3d7-6fef-4358-83e7-f7e333eb8675"}
mc: <DEBUG> Response Time:  3.844982ms

---------START-HTTP---------
PUT /minio/admin/v3/add-canned-policy?name=ReplicationRemoteUserPolicy.json HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx:xxxx
User-Agent: MinIO (linux; amd64) madmin-go/0.0.1 mc/RELEASE.2022-07-06T14-54-36Z
Content-Length: 1328
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=admin/20220707//s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=**REDACTED**
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: 26a5f72146edcd356b967fb84a6b1407418205af1904f9408fd2e85b196c98d1
X-Amz-Date: 20220707T094030Z

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 237
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 07 Jul 2022 09:40:19 GMT
Server: MinIO
Vary: Origin
X-Amz-Request-Id: 16FF82A1BB2425B5
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

{"Code":"XMinioMalformedIAMPolicy","Message":"conditions are not supported for action s3:GetBucketVersioning","Resource":"/minio/admin/v3/add-canned-policy","RequestId":"16FF82A1BB2425B5","HostId":"3473e3d7-6fef-4358-83e7-f7e333eb8675"}
---------END-HTTP---------
mc: <ERROR> Unable to add new policy: conditions are not supported for action s3:GetBucketVersioning
 (1) admin-policy-add.go:140 cmd.mainAdminPolicyAdd(..) Tags: [cluster202, ReplicationRemoteUserPolicy.json, /dev/stdin]
 (0) admin-policy-add.go:140 cmd.mainAdminPolicyAdd(..)
 Commit:81c4a5ad6ee4 | Release-Tag:RELEASE.2022-07-06T14-54-36Z | Host:clone-instance-testv3 | OS:linux | Arch:amd64 | Lang:go1.18.3 | Mem:3.3 MB/17 MB | Heap:3.3 MB/7.7 MB.
```

How can I fix this?

I used helm chart install minio cluster, the tag of docker images is :RELEASE.2021-02-14T04-01-33Z

Comment: Could you share the policy used?

Comment: Also there is a fix may be related to this https://github.com/minio/minio/pull/11546 so could you try with most recent version?

Comment: Also how are you running MinIO? The error seems to imply that you do not have versioning enabled on the bucket. Can you confirm? For your version of MinIO, if you are running with a single node and single drive, you are in filesystem mode and cannot use replication.